# PL/SQL-Why is the salary not increased by 20%?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

When I enter employee_id, the salary does not increase by 20%, it changes to 6336$ regardless of job_title or Salary amount. Is it because of wrong IF Statement? How can I solve this problem? Also, there is a yellow wavy line under SELECT. What does it mean? I am using Oracle SQL Developer.

My code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE raise_emp_salaries (
p_emp_id IN NUMBER) AS

CURSOR c_emp IS
SELECT
    country_name,
    job_title,
    employees.employee_id,
    salary
FROM employees 
    JOIN departments on departments.department_id = employees.department_id
    JOIN locations on locations.location_id = departments.location_id
    JOIN countries ON countries.country_id = locations.country_id
    JOIN jobs ON jobs.job_id = employees.job_id;

rec_emp   c_emp%rowtype;
new_sal   NUMBER(9,2);
 
BEGIN 
OPEN c_emp; 
SAVEPOINT update_no;
LOOP
FETCH c_emp INTO rec_emp;
EXIT WHEN c_emp%notfound;

IF rec_emp.country_name = 'United States of America'
AND rec_emp.job_title IN ('Administration Assistant','Stock Manager') THEN
new_sal := rec_emp.salary * 1.20;
END IF;

   UPDATE employees
SET
    employees.salary = new_sal
WHERE
    employees.employee_id = p_emp_id;
COMMIT;  
end loop;
close c_emp;
end;`
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables; the `INSERT` statements for the sample data; and the expected output from your procedure.

Comment: Your cursor must first also  be filtered by the `p_emp_id,` otherwise it will always update with the last row in the cursor, likely not related to the intended `p_emp_id`. Moreover, you are updating the `p.emp_id` with the salaries of all the employees, one per cursor iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a cursor, use a single `UPDATE` statement:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE raise_emp_salaries(
  p_emp_id IN NUMBER
)
AS
BEGIN 
  UPDATE employees e
  SET   salary = salary * 1.2
  WHERE employee_id = p_emp_id
  AND   EXISTS(
          SELECT 1
          FROM   departments d
                 INNER JOIN locations l
                 ON l.location_id = d.location_id
                 INNER JOIN countries c
                 ON c.country_id = l.country_id
          WHERE  d.department_id = e.department_id
          AND    c.country_name = 'United States of America'
        )
  AND   EXISTS(
          SELECT 1
          FROM   jobs j
          WHERE  j.job_id = e.job_id
          AND    j.job_title IN ('Administration Assistant','Stock Manager')
        );
END;
/
```

*Note: Using `COMMIT` in the procedure means that you cannot chain multiple procedures and/or DML statements together in a single transaction and then use `ROLLBACK` on them all if a later one fails. You should remove the `COMMIT` and call it outside the procedure when the transaction is complete.*

---

> Is it because of wrong IF Statement? How can I solve this problem?

Your procedure has several flaws:

1. As userMT points out in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70979302/1509264), the `UPDATE` statement is outside the `IF` statement so you will update the `p_emp_id` record for every row in the cursor with the most recent matching salary.
2. You do not filter the rows in the `SELECT` statement so every employee will appear in the cursor.

If you want to do it with a cursor (you should not) then you want something like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE raise_emp_salaries (
  p_emp_id IN NUMBER
)
AS
  CURSOR c_emp IS
  SELECT employees.employee_id,
         salary
  FROM   employees 
         JOIN departments on departments.department_id = employees.department_id
         JOIN locations on locations.location_id = departments.location_id
         JOIN countries ON countries.country_id = locations.country_id
         JOIN jobs ON jobs.job_id = employees.job_id
  WHERE  country_name = 'United States of America'
  AND    job_title IN ('Administration Assistant','Stock Manager')
  AND    employee_id = p_emp_id;

  rec_emp   c_emp%rowtype;
BEGIN 
  OPEN c_emp; 
  LOOP
    FETCH c_emp INTO rec_emp;
    EXIT WHEN c_emp%notfound;

    UPDATE employees
    SET   salary      = c_emp.salary * 1.2
    WHERE employee_id = c_emp.employee_id;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c_emp;
END;
/
```

*(This assumes that each employee can only be in one department and that departments are in one location and in one country and that employees only have one job. If there can be more than one then there will be repeated updates. It also assumes that `p_emp_id` matches one employee; if you can match multiple employees then the cursor solution will still have issues.)*

Answer (score 1):

Your `UPDATE` statement is outside the `IF` checking for country & title; it updates everyone's salary with the last new_sal the loop detected. Move it inside the IF..ENDIF.